# Undefined variable: photos (View: C:\wamp64\www\couture\resources\views\upload.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

i want to fix the undifined variable $photos
upload.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
        <h1>voir les modeles</h1>
            <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <input type="file" name="image">
                <input type="submit" name="Upload">
            </form>
        </hr>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($photos as $photo)
            <li> {{ $photo->name }}<img src="{{ asset('storage/images/', $photo->name) }}"></li>

            @endforeach
        </ul>
@endsection
```

here is the controler photo`enter code here`

PhotoController

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Photo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PhotoController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        $photos = Photo::all();
        return view('upload', compact('photos'));
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        // dd($request->file());
        $size = $request->file('image')->getSize();
        $name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

        $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images/', $name);
        $photo = new Photo();
        $photo->name = $name;
        $photo->size = $size;
        $photo->save();

        return redirect()->back();
     }
}






enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public function create()
> {
>     $photos = Photo::all();
>     return view('upload', ['photo =>$photos'] );
>
> }
> ```

should be,

`return view('upload', ['photos' => $photos]);`

Notice the incorrect placement of the single quote and the singular use of *photo*.

Also, please ask an actual question and don't just dump the error into the title.

Comment: i just post my blade file this is my fisrt use of stackoverflow and my english is not top excuse me for some errors

Comment: @JoanLeonelKenfack No problem. Please keep your question's code up to date so we know what you've tried. Edit your question and make all the most recent changes. Try to keep the formatting neat.  Thx.

Comment: If you've made the suggested edit in your code and you're still getting the error, then I think something else is going on. Perhaps a new error?

Comment: everything is ok now here are all my files

Comment: So, no more issues? All working OK?

Comment: still the same error

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I USE LAREVEL 8

Comment: OK, and you're sure you're not referencing `$photos` in the layout or some other view linked to this? Because your code should work based on what you've shared with us. My personal preference is not to use `compact` because it isn't listed in the docs, but I know people use it successfully. Please read https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views and try to debug a bit further. Look at line numbers too to see if it's failing in the spot you think it is. Good luck.

Comment: i'm sure because these 2 files are the only ones used for my work  thanks for your help

Comment: You also use layouts.blade.php. See `@extends('layouts.app')`.

Answer (score 0):

Change create function code.

```
public function create()
{
    $photos = Photo::all();
    return view('upload', ['photos' => $photos] );
}
```

Check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views).

Comment: i stil got the same error $photos is undefined

Comment: Show your Blade code.

Comment: i just post my blade file this is my fisrt use of stackoverflow and my english is not top excuse me for some errors